# Create a semi circle pie char with variable attribute heights

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, d3.js

I am new to JS and looking at the charts on http://d3js.org/ and I am having trouble understanding how to manipulate them. Basically I want to use the animated donut chart but I only want to display a half circle as well as different heights for each attribute(section in the pie). I have taken a look at some of the other tutorials and I just can't seem to wrap my head around it, any help would be greatly appreciated.

here is the code I am using:

```
var resume_dataset =
    [
    {job:"", start:2007, end: 2009, color: "#eb9ca1"},
    {job:"", start:2008, end: 2010, color: "#f9a482"},
    {job:"", start:2010, end: 2011, color: "#d0ebe9"},
    {job:"", start:2013, end: 2014, color: "#cccc99"},
    {job:"", start:2012, end: 2013.25, color: "#ffcc99"},
    {job:"", start:2011, end: 2014, color:"#9999cc"}
    ];

    function year_to_angle(year) {
        return ((year - 2007)*Math.PI)/7-(Math.PI/2.0);
    }

    var width = 960,
        height = 500,
        radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

    var color = d3.scale.category20();

    var degree = Math.PI/180;


    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(radius - 180)
        .outerRadius(function(datum, i) { if(i != undefined){datum._i = i}; return radius - 30 + datum._i *10} );

    var job_arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(radius - 180)
        .outerRadius(function(d){return radius - 30 + 20*(d.start-2007)})
        .startAngle(function(d){return year_to_angle(d.start)})
        .endAngle(function(d){return year_to_angle(d.end)})
        //.onMouseOver(function(d){$(d.job).attr("class", "highlight")})

    var svg = d3.select("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + (height - 70)  + ")");

    var path = svg.selectAll("path")
        .data(resume_dataset)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("fill", function(d){return d.color})
        .attr("d", job_arc).attr("opacity", 0.7)




    </script>
```

Got it figured out! thanks for everyone's contributions!

Comment: This is the second question I've seen on half-pie charts today. What is your goal in attempting to represent your data this way? Is it a contrived example just to exercise your skills with D3? Otherwise, I'd suggest using a different visualization (http://www.perceptualedge.com/articles/08-21-07.pdf). Half a pie chart is likely to be half as good rather than half as bad.

Comment: I completely agree with your view on pie charts, however this particular case was more of a brain exercise/for the sake of aesthetics. I really appreciated the paper though, good read, thank you for taking the time to share that.

Comment: I just thought it was a bit odd that I came across 2 questions from 2 different people on the same day regarding half pie charts. I even checked to make sure it wasn't one person posting twice. I've also been known to create contrived meaningless examples just to exercise code (http://bl.ocks.org/colin-young/5165614)

Comment: I saw those too, in fact the poster has also posted on this question. It was just a strange coincidence. I like your use of the d3.js force.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

concerning the half circle, you can set the .startAngle and .endAngle in the pie-variable.

```
var degree = Math.PI/180; // just to convert the radian-numbers
var pie = d3.layout.pie().sort(null).startAngle(-90*degree).endAngle(90*degree);
```

Comment: hmm I tried plugging that in, now the chart doesnt seem to appear, any suggestions?

Comment: hm, works fine if i test the code with the two additions - did you replace the original pie-variable? do you get any javascript-error?

Comment: oddly enough I got it to work in all browsers except firefox, did you experience the same issue?

Comment: no, its working fine in firefox as well. maybe you could post your current code once again so we could have a look.

Comment: I dont have any idea why I wasn't able to get it to work in firefox, the updated code works perfectly cross browser. BTW I really like your animation script you have on your other question, super cool.

Comment: I made a few attempts to animate it like your chart at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15665652/d3-pie-chart-transition-with-attrtween do you have any suggestions for mine? I am trying to perform the same animation.